# loop over nested JSON object and build object for formData to write in database

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, loops, object

I have a JSON object (comes from my multi-step form) that looks like the following:

```
[
  {
    "title": "Personal Details",
    "fields": [
      {
        "label": "FirstName",
        "value": "John"
      },
      {
        "label": "SecondName",
        "value": "Doe"
      },
      {
        "label": "Age",
        "value": "22"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "title": "Address",
    "fields": [
      {
        "label": "City",
        "value": "New York"
      },
      {
        "label": "ZipCode",
        "value": "10001"
      },
      {
        "label": "County",
        "value": "NY County"
      },
      {
        "label": "State",
        "value": "NY"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I want to loop over this object and create a new object to use it as a formData object using "label" and "value" to write this data in my database. So the new object should look like the following:

```
{

FirstName: "John",
SecondName: "Doe",
Age: "22",
City: "New York",
Zipcode: "10001"
...

}
```

How to realize this in a loop or with forEach ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This sounds dangerous. Are you aware of the SQL injection vulnerability? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sql_injection#:~:text=SQL%20injection%20is%20mostly%20known%20as%20an%20attack,used%20to%20attack%20any%20type%20of%20SQL%20database.

Comment: @ControlAltDel  I use a secure backend. How would you prevent SQL injection here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the following snippet:

```js
const test = [
  {
    "title": "Personal Details",
    "fields": [
      {
        "label": "FirstName",
        "value": "John"
      },
      {
        "label": "SecondName",
        "value": "Doe"
      },
      {
        "label": "Age",
        "value": "22"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "title": "Address",
    "fields": [
      {
        "label": "City",
        "value": "New York"
      },
      {
        "label": "ZipCode",
        "value": "10001"
      },
      {
        "label": "County",
        "value": "NY County"
      },
      {
        "label": "State",
        "value": "NY"
      }
    ]
  }
]

const result = {};
test.forEach(obj => {
  obj.fields.forEach(field => {
    result[field.label] = field.value;
  });
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: That's great exactly what i wanted. I struggled with "fields". Thanks a lot.